# Can't create methods in a c# class ( Visual studio 2017)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

please i just encountered this problem and i dont know how to go about it. I've tried to reset Visual studio settings to no avail. 
 I just created a new class and when i try to create a method in it, i get the following errors;
**property or indexer must have at least one accessor**,
  **property or indexer cannot have a void type**

the problem is that i'm actually trying to create a method and not a property.
below is the class

```
public static class IoCContainer
{
    public static void Setup
    {

    }
}
```

I don't know if i mistakenly toogle a visual studio setting or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses `()` at the end of your function name.

So your code should be:

```
public static class IoCContainer
{
    public static void Setup()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sure thing. Just make sure to click the checkbox next to the question to mark it as an answer and close the question to prevent others from wasting time check this ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're missing the parenthesis after `Setup`. Changing to the following should fix your issue:

```
public static void Setup()
{

}
```

The compiler thought you were trying to create a Property due to the missing parens.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh thank you very much. how small a problem that was. I've been coding for almost 6hrs. I'm sure i didn't noticed that bc me brains was in a deadlock. thank you